# MySQL Partitioning. The partition function return wrong type

Tags: mysql, hash, partitioning

What is incorrect in the following query?

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_user_geolocation` (
            `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Идентификатор',
            `user_id` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID пользователя',
            `client_type` VARCHAR(38) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Тип клиента',
            `lat` DECIMAL(28,8) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Широта',
            `lon` DECIMAL(28,8) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Долгота',
            `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Дата создания',
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `user_id`)
        )
        PARTITION BY HASH(id+user_id) PARTITIONS 200;
```

Error: The partition function returns the wrong type. 1491.
This table using for save users geo-location data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass an integer to `HASH` function. But in your case `user_id` is of type `VARCHAR`.

> **[18.2.3. HASH Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-hash.html)**
>
> To partition a table using HASH partitioning, it is necessary to
>   append to the CREATE TABLE statement a PARTITION BY HASH (expr)
>   clause, where **expr is an expression that returns an integer**.

Comment: Just for curious, why hash function needs a integer ? varchar could also apply a hash function.